# Prepared Statement does not use expected index

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a very large table of IOT sample that I'm trying to run a relativly simple query against. Running the query normally using the MySql CLI returns a result in ~0.07 seconds. If I first prepare the query either via PDO or by running a SQL [PREPARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html) statement then the request takes over a minute.

I've enabled the the optimizer trace feature, and it looks like when the statement is prepared, MySql ignores the index that it should use and does a file sort of the whole table. I'd like any insight if I am doing something wrong or if this looks like a MySql bug.

The table itself contains over 100 million samples, and at least 300 thousand are associated with the device being queried here. I ran these tests with MySql 8.0.23, but when I upgraded to 8.0.25 the issues persisted.

**Table definition** (some data rows ommited)

```sql
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `samples` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `organization_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `device_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `raw_reading` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `samples_organization_id_foreign` (`organization_id`),
  KEY `samples_reverse_device_id_created_at_organization_id_index` (`device_id`,`created_at` DESC,`organization_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `samples_device_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `devices` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `samples_organization_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`organization_id`) REFERENCES `organizations` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=188315314 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**Sql That runs in < 1s**

```sql
select *
from `samples`
where `samples`.`device_id` = 5852
  and `samples`.`device_id` is not null
  and `id` != 188315308
order by `created_at` desc
limit 1;
```

**Sql That runs in over a minute**

```sql
prepare test_prep from 'select * from `samples` where `samples`.`device_id` = ? and `samples`.`device_id` is not null and `id` != ? order by `created_at` desc limit 1';
set @a = 5852;
set @b = 188315308;
execute test_prep using @a, @b;
```

Trace for the non prepared SQL can be found at [my gist](https://gist.github.com/kmorozov/7962fa56b90e67fbf7160f600dd0a992), but the relevant part is

```json
{
  "reconsidering_access_paths_for_index_ordering": {
    "clause": "ORDER BY",
    "steps": [
    ],
    "index_order_summary": {
      "table": "`samples`",
      "index_provides_order": true,
      "order_direction": "asc",
      "index": "samples_reverse_device_id_created_at_organization_id_index",
      "plan_changed": false
    }
  }
},
```

Trace for the prepared query can be found at [my other gist](https://gist.github.com/kmorozov/5f14b2a329f5e5600c4d137d547d8b93), but the relevant part is

```json
{
  "reconsidering_access_paths_for_index_ordering": {
    "clause": "ORDER BY",
    "steps": [
    ],
    "index_order_summary": {
      "table": "`samples`",
      "index_provides_order": false,
      "order_direction": "undefined",
      "index": "samples_reverse_device_id_created_at_organization_id_index",
      "plan_changed": false
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: `and samples.device_id is not null` is redundant; remove it.

Comment: Ya, I know. My framework (Laravel) adds that in as part of it's DB abstraction. It does not really affect the issue as it's the first thing the optimizer discards.

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to the implicit cast mysql uses for the parameters. Try checking how it goes if you prepare the code with hard coded parameter.

Comment: Have you considered running [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) to get performance/index specific optiziation info? Might be worth noting.

Comment: Alas, abstractions sometimes get in the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not full solution, but a workaround. I added an index on just my timestamp and that seems to satisfy the optimizer.

```sql
KEY `samples_created_at_index` (`created_at` DESC),
```

I'm going to try to clean up a minimal test case and post it over on MySql bugs. I'll add a followup here if anything comes of that.

Answer (score 0):

The index you want to use is not that bad:

```
`samples_reverse_device_id_created_at_organization_id_index`
  (`device_id`,`created_at` DESC,`organization_id`)
```

However, is not a covering index. If the query performance is really important, I would add an index that covers the filtering predicate at least. Your don't need a real covering index since you are retrieving all columns. I would try:

```
create index ix1 on samples (device_id, created_at, id);
```

**EDIT**

Another trick that could promote the index usage is to delay the predicate `id != 188315308` as much as possible. If you know that this predicate will be matched by at least one row in the first 100 rows produced by the rest of the predicates you can try rephrasing your query as:

```
select *
from (
  select *
  from `samples`
  where `samples`.`device_id` = 5852
  order by `created_at` desc
  limit 100
) x
where `id` != 188315308
order by `created_at` desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Interesting. I assumed that the Id is part of the index by default. The optimizer trace seems to imply that it is. I'll give that a try.

Comment: @KirillMorozov You are absolutely right. I don't deal with clustered tables very often, so please disregard the first part of the answer.

Comment: Technically, that is not "covering" since there are more columns in `*`.  It does, however, "cover" the `WHERE`. And, if the Optimizer is cleaver enough, also the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this, since the `= 5852` assures that it will be false:

```
 and `samples`.`device_id` is not null
```

Then your index, or this one, should work fine.

```
 INDEX(device_id, created_at, id)
```

Do not use @variables; the Optimizer seems to not look at the value they contain.  That is, instead of

```
set @a = 5852;
set @b = 188315308;
execute test_prep using @a, @b;
```

Simply do

```
execute test_prep using 5852, 188315308;
```

Consider writing a bug report at bugs.mysql.com

I suspect `"order_direction": "undefined"` is part of the problem.